# I need a particular number of "success" in response data by sending the same request

Tags: jmeter

I am getting a text in the response data "success". i am using while controller with a `http request`, `counter`, `regx`. `regx` is capturing the text, counter is to increment the count. and i want the while controller to run until i get say 5 times success in the response data

```
while controller ${__jexl3("${variable}" ="Successful" && ${counter} = 5)}
http request
regx
counter
```

it became an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

the equality operator in JEXL is "==" (you see section "Operators" in documentation: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html), besides the while loop should go until the counter variable is less equal to 5. So the condition should be set like this:

```
while controller ${__jexl3("${variable}" == "Successful" && ${counter} <= 5)}
```

i hope this helps

Comment: to apply the same I even tried 
while controller  
condition =
${__javaScript("${variable__matchNr}" != "${Counter }",)}

Inside while controller ..i have added http request and post processor to capture variable = Successful
match no.   -1
also defined the counter in User defined variables and kept the value as 5.

Still while controller is going in infinite loop.

Comment: try with parseInt javascript: ${__javaScript("${variable}" == "Successful" && parseInt("${counter}",10) <= 5)}

Answer (score 0):

I have added a regular expression with reference name variable to capture the word "successful "from response data and match no as -1 .

And in while controller 
Condition = ${__javaScript("${variable_matchNr}" =="${counter}",)}

And added http request (with same regx)and pause

It worked.

Thanks .